# How to filter values in Multiple selection using textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have a text box and multiple selection box. When ever I write something in text box it will filter that text in the multiple selection and show only matched value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <select id="uniqueCarNames" name="cars" multiple>
        <option value="volvo">Long Distance Travel</option>
        <option value="saab">Amazing </option>
        <option value="opel">Excellent Travelling</option>
        <option value="audi">I am rich</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="filterMultipleSelection" />
</body>

</html>
```

So if I start writing in input box it will start filtering the values in selection box. I want the filtering using text of option tag.
Please guide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.filter(function)` jQuery method can be used to find the target option elements and show them as follows. The JavaScript method `.toLowerCase()` is used to make the search `case-insensitive`:

```js
$('#filterMultipleSelection').on('input', function() {
    var val = this.value.toLowerCase();
    $('#uniqueCarNames > option').hide()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.value.toLowerCase().indexOf( val ) > -1;
    })
    .show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <select id="uniqueCarNames" name="cars" multiple>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="opel">Opel</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="filterMultipleSelection" />
```

Comment: I am thankful for the solution, I need one favour . Here you have filtered using option value, how can I do if my value and text of option tag is different. Like for <option value="audi">Master Car</option>, how can I filter using text "Master Car".

Comment: I changed .value to .text and its working.. It was my error . Sorry :)

Comment: Use return $(this).text().toLower... instead.