# Input box as a selection menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to use the usual Input box + Select box and style them to make something like [selectize's](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) textbox and  box?
just like the email's box? I tried to understand their jQuery code but totally didn't understand any thing, So i was wondering if there is an easy and quick way to program this specific part by myself, i searched at Google to see any tutorial about that but couldn't find any.

Comment: Hi, the idea itself is simple. it's an input element of type text, when the focused it has shows a list of elements (li/div/span whatever you want) and position it exactly under the input and style it so it looks like it's connected to the input (the input bottom border is short)

Comment: @Saar wouldn't that count as creating my own <select> but using <div>s and <li>s and <span>s?

Comment: sorry, I missed that part. however the idea is the quite the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the idea itself is simple. it's an input element of type text, when the focused it has shows a list of elements (li/div/span whatever you want) and position it exactly under the input and style it so it looks like it's connected to the input (the input bottom border is short)

I did a very small example for you, try to ignore the bad styling.. just understand the idea.

```css
.formContainer{
background-color:lightblue;
height:600px;
width: 600px;
}
#nameSelector{
width:400px;
border: 4px solid green;
}

#nameSelector:focus{
border-bottom:1px solid green;
}

#nameList{
list-style:none;
display:none;
margin:0;
margin-left:4px;
padding:0;
width:400px;
}
#nameList li{
background-color:lightgrey;
}

#nameList li:nth-child(even){
background-color:white;
}


#nameSelector:focus+#nameList{
display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="formContainer">
  <input id="nameSelector" type="text"/>
  <ul id="nameList">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Jane</li>
    <li>Celine</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, That would work, But how to make it as a token as they did? If for example the value isn't available or selected the input returns to default value(empty) And when it is selected it is put in a box.

Comment: You need to add some javascript but onClick and just add a square and position it on the input box and remove it from the names list.

Comment: Yes, That the part i really want an example of it, I'm trying to link the values with AJAX to the database but really can't figure out how to make the values of the box disappear if not selected.

Comment: in the javascript document.querySelectorAll("#nameList > li"); then use a loop li.addEventListener("click", function(ev){let target = ev.targetElement; target.parentElement.removeChild(target)}); this will remove the item from the list. now use the target to create a span inside of the formContainer and position it on the input box;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879679/how-to-filter-values-in-multiple-selection-using-textbox-value) to make your textbox filter a select box and, using css, make the correct adjustment.

You could even create your jquery plugin to apply like 
`$('myInputText').createOptionList({...});`

Comment: that is awesome but i'm trying to understand how to make delete the values if it is not in the datalist And when the datalist selected it is saved in a block and can be limited.